# Configuration annotations error: Argument 'fn' is not a function, got string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I've used annotations everywhere (in controllers, services,...) except for a few files. As I'm getting problems with minification, I'm rewriting these last few files.

This is my current config:

```
(function () {

    angular.module('app')
        .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $provide, $httpProvider, showErrorsConfigProvider, LightboxProvider) {
            $httpProvider.interceptors.push('requestsErrorHandler');
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
            showErrorsConfigProvider.showSuccess(true);

            // more code
            // routing and stuff...


        });

}());
```

This works fine. I'm now trying to rewrite this with annotations:

```
(function () {

    angular.module('app')
        .config('configurationapp', configurationapp);

    configurationapp.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$provide', '$httpProvider', 'showErrorsConfigProvider', 'LightboxProvider'];

    function configurationapp($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $provide, $httpProvider, showErrorsConfigProvider, LightboxProvider) {
            $httpProvider.interceptors.push('requestsErrorHandler');
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
            showErrorsConfigProvider.showSuccess(true);


            // more code
            // routing and stuff


        }
}());
```

However, I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got string
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error. I've done **exactly** the same as with all other files, still this doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: May be some module is failing to load.
Please have a look at your browser's console to see if any files are not being downloaded/loaded correctly.

Comment: Nope, everything seems to be fine. I'm sure the problem is related to this code, as when I revert the changes, everything works again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A string was provided to `config`:

```
angular.module('app')
    .config('configurationapp', configurationapp);
```

It expects a single argument, function or array. `configurationapp` isn't Angular service and shouldn't be named:

```
angular.module('app')
    .config(configurationapp);
```

Comment: So my old syntax was perfectly fine for minification?

Comment: Not really. You should use array annotation https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#inline-array-annotation for minification.

Comment: @Bv202 I personally consider 'new' syntax (so-called John Papa style) more verbose and less readable, I would suggest to stick to recommended Angular syntax, unless you know that the code will benefit from 'new' one.

Comment: Okay, it works with the array annotation. But why does it and why doesn't it work with $inject?

Comment: Mmm okay, thanks for the answer! With the inline array annotation, minification seems to work fine! Thanks!

Comment: Same problem when using app run this way

Answer (score 1):

Try this syntax. I find the inline annotation easier than the explicitly inject dependencies:

```
  (function () {

    angular.module('app')
        .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$provide', '$httpProvider', 'showErrorsConfigProvider', 'LightboxProvider',
        function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $provide, $httpProvider, showErrorsConfigProvider, LightboxProvider) {
            $httpProvider.interceptors.push('requestsErrorHandler');
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
            showErrorsConfigProvider.showSuccess(true);

            // more code
            // routing and stuff...


        }]);

}());
```